# Model View Controller pattern in REST HTTP client

Tags: rest, design-patterns, model-view-controller, model, coding-style

I am a bit confused what should Model consist of in the case of REST client. Let's assume I want to have a client to communicate with server via REST. No database.

Example: I want to send a POST HTTP request with some form data to a server. Where should I put methods like *construct_REST_request()* or *execute_REST_request()*? In Controller or in Model? In model theoretically should be business logic objects. Does it mean in Model should be only data that Controller uses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Models are your business objects,  this need not to be database always - but essentially target objects on which controllers will operate.

Controllers executes business logic 'to and from' the models/objects, based on the request from view or other exposure of your REST controllers to the outer world. The example method you given should be part of controller

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response! Could you please give me some example of a business logic for my case? I am still not sure if constructing a REST (f.g curl) request would be a part of an application logic or a business logic...

Comment: Sure, but before that - you need to be elaborated on - "my case" ... I don't know what you are doing in your rest service.

Comment: execute_REST_request() goes in controller ... What this method supposed to do in your case?

Comment: All right. My HTTP server is a host for its subunits- clusters (and servers in  clusters). My client will manage those units. Operations such as start/stop, check status, restart, deploy an application to a cluster etc.

Comment: My tool will construct valid REST request (sets proper URL, options, data forms etc) from user command and execute it (sends just constructed REST HTTP request to the HTTP server)

Comment: That means your controller is going to construct proper command to apply on a set of servers / ip / resources. So, you can have a model defined to represent the server as object, with properties like name, ip, os ... Constructor to initiate some preloads etc. also be known that models can have their methods as behaviors, say your server may have methods to start(), stop() etc. controllers will receive API requests and process server operations based on that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93310/discussion-between-konrad-and-arif).